# correlation between features with R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, feature-selection

I wanna calculate the correlation of features, every feature consists of a 50*100 matrix. My question is how can I use R to calculate the correlation between features, instead of correlation of columns inside the matrix.

Comment: Maybe correlation on transposed data?

Comment: convert the matrix to vector with `c( )` ~~ like this `cor( c(feature1), c(feature2) )` ?